# Is "cockfighting" between larvae of Prawns?

Tags: district-9

There is one brief scene in District 9 where humans are watching something like a cockfight but the creatures resemble the Prawns, but not exactly. Do we know if these are the Prawn larvae or just some species that are associated with the Prawn? We do know that young Prawns can resemble adults very closely -- we see the alien scientist's son is just a small Prawn but it is possible that there is an intermediate larval state.

Comment: I thought my answer here was pretty definitive, given the quote from the official artbook. Is there anything else you're looking for before considering an acceptance?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are described in the [*Art of District 9*](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/9603367-the-art-of-district-9) as being akin to pets. Not the same species as the aliens, but clearly possessing the same biology, much like a human and a monkey.

> As seen in the finished film, in the slums
> bets are made on **cockfights involving alien
> creatures that presumably came on the ship
> with the Prawns.** Designers David Meng and
> Christian Pearce offered options that were
> intended to be **clearly from the same home
> world, with crustacean anatomy.** Early ideas
> about them perhaps wearing blades or other
> improvised weapons were dropped in favor of
> a nasty tail barb. The final design maquette
> (facing page) was sculpted by Weta sculptor
> Don Brooker.
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

The CG team for the film describes them as being '*lobster-like alien creatures*'

> The Embassy key-frame animated, rendered, and composited the Exo-suit
> for seamless scene integration. In total, The Embassy worked on just
> over 100 shots, mostly in the film’s 12-minute climactic battle
> sequence. The company also created small lobster-like alien creatures
> used by both the Aliens and Humans in a type of cockfight.
>
> <sub><sup>[The Embassy Re-Teams with Director Neill Blomkamp on ‘District 9’](https://www.cgarena.com/newsworld/district9.html)</sup></sub>

Comment: given that humans were watching, how much more interesting it would have been if indeed these creatures had been larvae -- and i am sure many people guessed this. not really sure what the point of having this scene is, really. they look rather like face-huggers, do they not?

Comment: @releseabe - I assumed, when I first saw the film, that these were alien larvae.